# React/AntDesign How to make rows draggable? (Table Drag Sorting)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop, antd

I have been coding this simple one-column drag and drop table, but the rows aren´t moving when I drag them. Where do I fix or check that?

I'm using React, AntDesign and JavaScript (with TypeScript)

```
import * as React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Table } from "antd";

import { DndProvider, DragSource, DropTarget } from "react-dnd";

import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

import update from "immutability-helper";

let dragingIndex = -1;

interface propsDD {
    isOver: any,
    connectDragSource: any,
    connectDropTarget: any,
    moveRow: any,
    restProps: {
        readonly [x: string]: any;
        children?: React.ReactNode;
    }
    className: any,
    index: any,
}

class BodyRow extends React.Component<propsDD>{
    render() {
        const { isOver, connectDragSource, connectDropTarget, moveRow, ...restProps } = this.props;
        const style = { ...restProps, cursor: 'move' };
        let { className } = restProps;
        if (isOver) {
            if (restProps.index > dragingIndex) {
                className += " drop-over-downward";
            }
            if (restProps.index < dragingIndex) {
                className += " drop-over-upward";
            }
        }
        return connectDragSource(
            connectDropTarget(
                <tr {...restProps} className={className} style={style} />
            )
        );
    }
}

const rowSource = {
    beginDrag(props: any) {
        dragingIndex = props.index;
        return {
            index: props.index,
        };
    },
};

const rowTarget = {
    drop(props: any, monitor: any) {
        const dragIndex = monitor.getItem().index;
        const hoverIndex = props.index;
        if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) {
            return;
        }
        props.moveRow(dragIndex, hoverIndex);
        monitor.getItem().index = hoverIndex;
    },
};

const DragableBodyRow = DropTarget("row", rowTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver()
}))(
    DragSource("row", rowSource, connect => ({
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource()
    }))(BodyRow)
);

const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Orden de Ejecución',
        dataIndex: 'attributes.name',
        key: 'name',
    },
];

type propsFromList = {
    receivedTasks: Task[],
    onReceivedTasks: (tasks: Task[]) => void,
}

export default class DDTasks extends React.Component<propsFromList, State>{
    public state: State = {
        data: [],
    };

    components = {
        body: {
            row: DragableBodyRow,
        },
    };

    onReceivedTasks(tasks: Task[]): void {
        this.setState({
            data: this.props.receivedTasks,
        } as State)
    }

    moveRow = (dragIndex: any, hoverIndex: any) => {
        const { data } = this.state;
        const dragRow = data[dragIndex];
        this.setState(
            update(this.state, {
                data: {
                    $splice: [[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragRow]]
                }
            })
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            < DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend} >
                <Table
                    rowKey="id"
                    bordered={true}
                    pagination={false}
                    columns={columns}
                    dataSource={this.props.receivedTasks}
                    components={this.components}
                    onRow={(index) => ({
                        index,
                        moveRow: this.moveRow,
                    })}
                />
            </DndProvider >
        );
    }
}
```

I expect to drag rows. The content of the rows are actually displayed.

Comment: I have already added the CSS style for the dragging effect (drop-over-downward & drop-over-upward).

Comment: Here is a gif of the actual behavior https://makeagif.com/i/TIw7Qx

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example I came up with based off of a lot of different things I found online and eventually formulated something that worked for my code:

Basically this is the body of a react component table getting called and I am mapping a list of places via the indexes and each row is draggable to allow the user to modify the table. I have also included the function calls associated with the  attributes

```
return (
        <Tbody>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <Tr key={index} className="item.name"
                        draggable={true}
                        onDragStart={this.dragstart}
                        onDragEnd={this.dragend}
                        onDragLeave={this.dragend}
                        onDragEnter={this.dragend}
                        onDrop={this.drop}
                        onDragOver={this.dragend}
                        id={index} >
                        <Td><span>{item.name}</span></Td>
                        <Td><span>{item.latitude}</span></Td>
                        <Td><span>{item.longitude}</span></Td>
                        <Td type="data"><span>{this.checkForZero(this.props.propDistances[index])}</span></Td>
                        <Td type="data"><span>{this.checkForZero(this.props.propCumulativeDist[index])}</span></Td>
                    </Tr>
            ))}
            {this.finishItineraryTable()}
        </Tbody>
    );

dragstart(event) {
    let dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    let node = event.target;
    dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',node.innerHTML);
    dataTransfer.setData('id',node.id);
    event.stopPropagation();
}

dragend(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let dragObjHtml = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    let dragObjId = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("id"));
    let dropTarget = event.target.closest("tr");
    let temp = dropTarget.innerHTML;
    dropTarget.innerHTML = dragObjHtml;
    dragObjId.innerHTML = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before a paste my long blob of code, I want to mention a few things:

- It's heavily based on the [original drag sorting example](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-drag-sorting).
- Luckily [React DnD](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/) has perfect TypeScript support as it's written in TypeScript.
- The code below is a drop in replacement for Ant designs `<table>`.
- It's generic.
- It uses functional components and hooks.
- There is a `onDragSort`, which gets called back every time some drag sort happened. The parameter includes the sorted data.

First install the packages `react-dnd` and `react-dnd-html5-backend`. Add this to your `DragSortingTable.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Table, { TableProps, TableComponents } from 'antd/lib/table';
import { DndProvider, DropTarget, DragSource, DragElementWrapper, DropTargetSpec } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

let dragingIndex = -1;

interface BodyRowProps {
  isOver: boolean;
  connectDragSource: DragElementWrapper<{}>;
  connectDropTarget: DragElementWrapper<{}>;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  index: number;
  className?: string;
}

const BodyRow: React.FC<BodyRowProps> = props => {
  const style = { ...props.style, cursor: 'move' };

  let { className } = props;
  if (props.isOver) {
    if (props.index > dragingIndex) {
      className += ' drop-over-downward';
    }
    if (props.index < dragingIndex) {
      className += ' drop-over-upward';
    }
  }

  return props.connectDragSource(
    props.connectDropTarget(
      <tr className={className} style={style}>
        {props.children}
      </tr>
    )
  );
};

const rowSource = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    dragingIndex = props.index;
    return {
      index: props.index
    };
  }
};

interface DropProps {
  index: number;
  moveRow: (dragIndex: number, hoverIndex: number) => void;
}

const rowTarget: DropTargetSpec<DropProps> = {
  drop(props, monitor) {
    const dragIndex = monitor.getItem().index;
    const hoverIndex = props.index;

    // Don't replace items with themselves
    if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) {
      return;
    }

    // Time to actually perform the action
    props.moveRow(dragIndex, hoverIndex);

    // Note: we're mutating the monitor item here!
    // Generally it's better to avoid mutations,
    // but it's good here for the sake of performance
    // to avoid expensive index searches.
    monitor.getItem().index = hoverIndex;
  }
};

const DragableBodyRow = DropTarget<DropProps>('row', rowTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver()
}))(
  DragSource('row', rowSource, connect => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource()
  }))(BodyRow)
);

interface DragSortingTableProps<T> extends TableProps<T> {
  onDragSort?: (sortedData: T[]) => void;
}

type extractTableType<T> = T extends DragSortingTableProps<infer T> ? T : never;

export const DragSortingTable: <T>(
  props: DragSortingTableProps<T>
) => React.ReactElement<DragSortingTableProps<T>> = props => {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = React.useState(props.dataSource);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDataSource(props.dataSource);
  }, [props.dataSource]);

  const components: TableComponents = {
    body: {
      row: DragableBodyRow
    }
  };

  const moveRow: DropProps['moveRow'] = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    const dragRow = dataSource[dragIndex];
    const remaining = dataSource.filter(i => i !== dragRow);
    const sorted = [...remaining.slice(0, hoverIndex), dragRow, ...remaining.slice(hoverIndex)];

    setDataSource(sorted);

    if (props.onDragSort) {
      props.onDragSort(sorted);
    }
  };

  const tableProps: TableProps<extractTableType<typeof props>> = {
    ...props,
    className: props.className ? props.className + ' drag-sorting-table' : 'drag-sorting-table',
    components,
    dataSource,
    onRow: (_record, index) => ({ index, moveRow })
  };

  return (
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <Table {...tableProps}>{props.children}</Table>
    </DndProvider>
  );
};
```

Add the following styles to your `antd.less` overwrites:

```
.drag-sorting-table tr.drop-over-downward td {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed @primary-color;
}

.drag-sorting-table tr.drop-over-upward td {
  border-top: 2px dashed @primary-color;
}
```

Use your new drag sorting table as follows:

```
<DragSortingTable<Users>
      dataSource={props.users}
      rowKey='id'
    >
      <Column
        title='Title'
        dataIndex='id'
        key='id'
      />
</DragSortingTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added CSS of antd sortable table to show the dragging effect?

```
#components-table-demo-drag-sorting tr.drop-over-downward td {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #1890ff;
}

#components-table-demo-drag-sorting tr.drop-over-upward td {
  border-top: 2px dashed #1890ff;
}
```

here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-pasteur-81odq)

Comment: Yes, I have already added the CSS style, as you said. In previous tests, the dragging effect showed, however, in this version doesn´t.

Comment: Which version of antd you are using can you update your antd version and then check

Comment: I´m not really sure about which AntD version I´m using, however, here is the original source code I´m trying to replicate: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-drag-sorting

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for a similar feature
and developed my own component with multi-row drag-drop support with the help of antd tables.

drag-drop table rows to reorder table data.

users can select multiple rows by "cntrl + click"

https://github.com/sojinantony01/react-multi-row-dragable-table-antd